# solving convolution for symbols and function in matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

i want to solve a convolution in matlab for two heaviside functions, 
the problem is that the matlab wont let me do this and pops an error saying:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
```

this is what i try to do:

```
syms x;
conv(heaviside(-1-x), heaviside(x+3))
```

i guess i can make a vector with the values that x can have and conv it using the vector but i dont want to predefine the range so i want to keep it a symbol.

any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this works: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28157-convolution ?

Answer (score 3):

You can compute convolution directly from definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), e.g. calculate integral:

```
syms x t  
symb_conv = int(heaviside(-1-(t-x)) * heaviside(x+3), x, -inf, inf)
```

**Edit:**

Really, it seems you convolution will be always infinity under these conditions.

Plots for original functions will be following:

```
ezplot(heaviside(-1-x), [-10 10])
ezplot(heaviside(x+3), [-10 10])
```

[image: heaviside(-x-1)]
[image: heaviside(x+3)]

We need to reflect one of function to receive convolution. Let it will be second function:

[image]

If we compare first and last plot we can see that these two functions has infinite non-zero intersection for x<-3. It is means that convolution for t=0 will be infinity.

If we try to shift last plot in any direction that we also will have infinite non-zero intersection for x<(-3-t). Therefore, final convolution function will be infinity for any t.

Comment: hello and thank you for your answer, i did it but it gives me an error "Warning: Explicit integral could not be found." and i cant use it in any way i mean i try to plot it but with no success.. can you help me out here? how would you plot this function?

Comment: hey, thanks for the example, i got it also but the problem is that its easy to plot the heavisides but i need the convolution between two function not necesserally heaviside...

Comment: @Anton.P Problem with "Warning: Explicit integral could not be found." exists for heavisides functions. For real functions this problem probably will not exists. Additionally, you always can compute this symbolic integral for some fixed set of t.